# How to group Prometheus data points in Grafana by variables

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Provided with these data points in Prometheus:

[image]

I would expect a line for each distinct `table` value in Grafana, but instead:

[image]

I'm getting one line per measurement. I'm likely to be missing something obvious, can someone help me understand what it is? Thank you

Comment: You seem to have ts as a label in the prometheus series.That means that each time a new time series is created as opposed to a single time series having multiple data points. 1 set of labels = 1 series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have ts as a label in the prometheus series.That means that each time a new time series is created as opposed to a single time series having multiple data points. 1 set of labels = 1 series.